# I'm struggling to write this simple SQL query with mongo

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE aaa = 321 AND bbb NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT bbb
                  FROM table
                  WHERE ccc = 123)
```

`aaa`, `bbb` and `ccc` are fields for the documents in the table and none of them are primary keys.

I know I could do one query first and then map the results into an array that I could use in the second query, but there are a lot of records in the table and it's not feasible to load them all in memory to produce the array that I'd need.

Tried playing with $lookup to write it all in a single query but I've not been able to do it :/

Any help will be appreciated, cheers!

Comment: are both 'aaa' and 'bbb' in the same 'table ?

Comment: @Visrozar yes everything is on the same table

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query. Without **aggregation**, you can do it with the help of **find**

```
db.table.find({
  aaa: 321,
  bbb: {
     $nin: await db.table.distinct("bbb", { ccc: 123 })
  }
})
```

Please use **async/await** function to get inner query result.

Comment: Thanks! The syntax is very nice but this still loads all the distinct values of `bbb` in memory, which makes my app run out of memory when I try to run it. :_(